# What is the easiest way to upload data from S3 to Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a simple way to load data from S3 to Redshift.

I've tried AWS Glue and Firehouse, without success.

EDIT:
As right now it's not the best way to do it but AWS Glue is working. I'll revist the COPY command to try to get better results!

Thanks guys!

Comment: redshift "copy" command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html or Redshift Spectrum .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the COPY command, e.g.

```
create table my_table(...);

copy my_table
from 's3://my_bucket/my_prefix/data.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>'
region 'us-west-2';
```

By default, the data file should contain pipe-separated plain text columns. There are plenty more options: JSON, Parquet, using a manifest file to load from multiple files, etc.

UNLOAD is the reverse command (dumping a table to S3).

Comment: @samvso The `COPY` command isn't just the simplest way to load data, it is the **recommended** way to load data.